# Scheduled execution with javascript

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, settimeout

I have a JavaScript array of function and delays in milliseconds:

```
var events = [
  {event: function_1, delay: 1234},
  {event: function_2, delay: 2456},
  ...
  {event: function_n, delay: 13154}
]
```

and a movie clip. The idea is when the movie is playing to execute the functions in the order given by the delay argument. One way to do this is:

```
video.play();
for ( var i = 0; i < events.length; i++ ) {
  setTimeout(events[i].event(), events[i].delay);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in order to guarantee the exact timing?

Comment: you can look into [requestAnimationFrames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). If the interval is fixed, you can even try `setInterval`. Something like this: `function initTimer(){ var count = 0; selInterval(function(){ events[count].event}, delay) }`

Comment: just use one timer via `setInterval`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a better way to code something. this sounds like a job for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you need them to be executed sequential? when the first executes, the second should start?

Comment: Yes, the second should start when the delay is reached.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov is the delay constant? if yes, you can check the snippet I have commented above

Comment: The delay rises progressively and is random. I have changed the values in order to express this.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate the events sequentially, you need a callback function to be called after each event. In the callback, you trigger the next event.

`events.shift()` removes the first event from the list. At the end of all the events being executed, the events list will remain empty.

```
var events = [
  { event: function_1, delay: 1000 },
  { event: function_2, delay: 2000 },
  { event: function_n, delay: 10100 }
];

function triggerEvents(events) {
    if(events.length === 0) {
        // all events completed
        return;
    }

    // get the first event from list
    var event = events.shift();    

    setTimeout(function () {
        event.event(function () {
            startEvents(events);
        });
    }, event.delay);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` with recursion.

**Note:** I have assumed that delay is increasing in fixed manner.

```js
var refresh_count = 0;
var delay = 1000;
var events = [
  { event: notify.bind(this, "test") }, 
  { event: notify.bind(this, "foo") }, 
  { event: notify.bind(this, "Hello World")}];

function notify(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

function initTimeout() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (events[refresh_count]) {
      events[refresh_count++].event();
      initTimeout();
    }
  }, delay + (refresh_count * 1000));
}

initTimeout();
```